# Excluding private/protected posts via IP

Tags: plugins, private, privileges

I essentially want password protected/private pages/posts in WP to work as they currently do, but completely disregard the functionality for certain IP addresses.

I've looked into filters/actions and don't see anything that seems promising, again I would prefer to do this without creating a specific category or anything outside of the current functionality of this in wordpress.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Bypass Password Protected Posts

You are, unfortunately right about the lack of filters, and hacking the core is inevitable. One solutions that seems to work revolves around the `sanitize_post_field()` function which fires off a number of interesting filters if its `$context` argument is not set to `raw`.

The template function that is responsible for deciding whether to show the password field or the content is http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L556

Notice how nice it would be to void the `post_password`? Let's dig in...

See how the post is acquired through the `get_post()` function:
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/post.php#L370

The function contains no filters or actions to hook into, but `sanitize_post_field()` contains some filters that can be hooked into, and `post_password` goes through that function.

Please refer to the function http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/post.php#L1676

Notice, however, that if `$context == 'raw';` the function returns, and none of the filters are fired off. So a little core hack is required that will make the flow of the code reach those filters.

```
// wp-includes/post.php, line 557
-- $post = get_post($post);
++ $post = get_post($post, null, 'display');
```

Will force the `$context` to be anything but `raw`. This will permit to do something along the following lines:

```
function wpse31407_bypass_password( $value, $post_id, $context ) {
    $allowed_ips = array( '127.0.0.1', '255.255.255.255', ... );
    if (in_array( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allowed_ips )) return '';
    else return $value;
}
add_filter( 'post_password', 'wpse31407_bypass_password', null, 3 );
```

This will effectively remove the password, so the test http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L556 `if ( empty($post->post_password) )` is evaluated to `true` allowing you to bypass the password. There should be no implications by getting the post with a `display` context, as it is used only for the retrieval of the `post_password`.

You can as well create your own filter in the core around the `post_password_required()` function mentioned above, not to overcomplicate things, maybe. Up to you.

### Bypass Private Posts

Now, as for private posts, refer to this bit or *query.php* http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/query.php#L2649 as this is where the found post get stripped off of private entries.

And you'd be tempted to hook into the http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/query.php#L2625 `posts_results` filter and go in and alter the `post_status` for each post from `private` to `public`... however, as you may have seen the `get_post_status()` function works on its own copy of a post that it gets from `get_post()`... ...which again has no filters but `sanitize_post_field()` does, which again requires a `$context` of anything but `raw`. So again:

```
// wp-includes/post.php, line 563
-- $post = get_post($post);
++ $post = get_post($post, null, 'display');
```

And hook into a filter to trick the function into thinking that the post is published by doing this:

```
function wpse31407_bypass_private( $value, $post_id, $context ) {
    $allowed_ips = array( '127.0.0.1', '255.255.255.255', ... );
    if (in_array( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allowed_ips )) return 'publish';
    else return $value;
}
add_filter( 'post_status', 'wpse31407_bypass_private', null, 3 );
```

Or wrap your own filter around the `get_post_status()` function.

### Conclusion

Once you understand which parts of the core are responsible for blocking the posts you can attempt to modify them however you require, so I hope my long answer helps to an extent, and someone follows up with more tips and perhaps better solutions. Great question, got me digging and thinking.

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback, out of curiosity, since post_status isn't a documented filter, does page status exist as well? I couldn't find either in the codebase via grep to be honest, but it worked!

Comment: Glad to have been of help. A page is a post, with a `post_type` of `page`. You won't find these via grep, as they are in the form of `'post_'.$field`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change core, just add action to `pre_get_posts` and do your check:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_anime_tax' );
function filter_anime_tax( $query ) {
    $ip = getUserIP();
    $ip_data = geoip_record_by_name( $ip );
    if( $ip_data['country_code'] != 'anything you want' ) { 
        $query->set( 'post_status', array( 'publish', 'private' ) );
    }
}
```

You can show or hide private posts to specific countries or IPs.